# Unable to execute method inside AWS Lambda function. TypeError this.method is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've recently switched to writing my AWS Lambda functions in TypeScript from vanillaJS as I use Angular so thought it'd be better for better muscle memory, but am running into the following error when trying to execute a method inside the lambda function.

```
{
"errorType": "TypeError",
"errorMessage": "this.test is not a function",
"stack": [
    "TypeError: this.test is not a function",
    "    at Runtime.lambda [as handler] (/var/task/index.js:17:249)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1028:29)"
]
```

}

How do I fix this? Have tried a few different ways but to no avail so far. P.S, I don't use Serverless framework or anything similar. This is just me writing and uploading as ZIP with AWS CLI. Function executes without this problem.

```
import { Context, APIGatewayProxyResult, APIGatewayEvent } from 'aws-lambda';

class Index {
    constructor() { }

    test() {
        return "test"
    }


    public async lambda(event: APIGatewayProxyResult, context: Context): Promise<any> {

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: this.test()
        }
    }
}

export const index = new Index()
export const handler = index.lambda
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed thanks to GitHub Co-Pilot suggestion (and btw, anyone that doesn't have this, $10 per month is a no-brainer. It's fantastic)

Needed to bind this to lambda function in my constructor.

```
constructor() {
    this.lambda = this.lambda.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for sharing - remember to mark your answer as accepted ;)